# Python 2.7 PyWebKitGTK Windows 8 Installation

Tags: python, python-2.7, webkit, gtk, pygtk

I already installed GTK, but now I'm trying to install webkit for Python 2.7 on Windows 8, but I can't find a pip or installation package anywhere. I tried qtwebkit but it wasn't really working with PyGTK. How do I install pywebkitgtk on Windows for Python 2.7?

Comment: Pywebkitgtk seems like it might be somewhat unmaintained, and the [downloads page](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pywebkitgtk/downloads) does not have Windows builds. I'm not experienced in Python so I don't know how their bindings work, but if they're all source, you might be able to install the tarballs in the folder containing your Python executable/script.

Comment: For what it's worth the modern approach is to use python-gobject instead of PyGTK and have that autogenerate the WebKitGTK bindings from the gobject introspection repository that comes with WebKitGTK. That should also work on Python 2.7.